# To list all datasets name and last refreshed datetime from PBI service API by using Python?

Tags: python, powerbi

My idea is using python to retrieve all datasets name and the last refreshed datetime and refreshed status, in Power BI Service by PBI API.

To do this, I have done following steps:

Step 1: Set up an Azure Active Directory (AAD) application, to get:

```
tenant_id
client_secret
client_id
```

Step 2: Install required Python packages

```
pip install requests
pip install msal
```

Step 3: python code

```
import requests
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
client_id = "xxxxxxxx-040d-4db7-8f43-de02b43fxxxx"
client_secret = "VQQ8Q~znvjp1ccNbyy1tVK6IBh2s2xxxxxxxxx"
tenant_id = "8cae7bf9-b754-4e93-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
scope = ["https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"]
api_endpoint = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets"

def get_access_token():
    app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id=client_id,
        client_credential=client_secret,
        authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
    )
    result = app.acquire_token_silent(scope, account=None)
    if not result:
        result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
    return result["access_token"]


def get_datasets():
    access_token = get_access_token()
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    response = requests.get(api_endpoint, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        datasets = response.json()["value"]
        for dataset in datasets:
            print("Dataset Name:", dataset["name"])
            print("Last Refreshed Date:", dataset["lastRefreshDateTime"])
    else:
        print("Failed to retrieve datasets. Status code:", response.status_code)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_datasets()
```

I did `print(access_token)` to make sure it has a value for successfully authorize process and it did have a value, but the output result when run code:

```
PS C:\Users\hungcht> & C:/Users/hungcht/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe "c:/Users/hungcht/Desktop/Y4A/PYTHON 3/project/ConnectPowerBIServiceAPI/connect_power_bi_service_api.py"       
Failed to retrieve datasets. Status code: 401
```

So anyone who experienced in this, can you show me how to fix the progress, and explain the why we have the error in progress.

I hope this question and your answers will be helpful for others in the future.

Comment: Do you have all the permission required for this? verify from this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/

Comment: Hi, I think i have verified all of indeed permission, can you check in this image? 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RxsoNYQfocmX5WdqpCZFceJdozZ-juCf/view?usp=drive_link

Answer (score 0):

Hi issue is being you are providing tenant ID instead of tenant name. Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tenant-management-read-tenant-name#get-your-tenant-name) to how to get the tenant name. Tenant ID approach has ben deprecated.

```
tenant_id = xxx.onmicrosoft.com
def get_access_token():
    app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
        client_id=client_id,
        client_credential=client_secret,
        authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
    )
```